# Getting access to objects in other parts of the object graph in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using iOS for this problem.

I have the following class structure:

1. ScheduleVC (With a UICollectionView ) who owns

   1. ScheduleCell (UICollectionViewCell) who owns

      1. ScheduleDayTVC (UITableViewController) who owns

         1. ScheduleDayCell (UITableViewCell) who owns
         2. OrderDetailView ( this is a view and is a subview of the ContentView)

There is an action in 5( OrderDetailView ) that needs to call 1( ScheduleVC ). There is only one ScheduleVC so my quick and dirty solution is to create a singleton class that gets me quick access.

Is this the best way to solve this? I didn't think passing down the pointer of 1 to 5 was very clean.

I also looked at KVO and it seemed that you needed a reference to both the observer and 'being observed' objects which I don't have anywhere.

Edit:
The top level VC owns a UICollectionView that has a layout similar to passbook or reminders. On each cell there is a TableView with it's own controller. Each UITableViewCell in this tableview has a view( 5 ) added to it's contentView. This view has a button when pressed needs to contact 1.

Comment: Why is a view owned by another controller (I'm assuming ScheduleDayTVC is "Table View Controller") required to talk to the ScheduleVC? I think you need to reconfigure that part of the design. Make the two controllers ask each other to do things; let the view just manage its screen space.

Comment: I added an edit to maybe add a little clarity. I also added the subclasses in my 'class structure'

Answer (score 0):

What do you need to call? is it a method to perform some business logic or to update the UI?

1. In the first case (business logic), it would be better to create a separate class (not a View Controller) and make it a singleton that can be invoked from anywhere without keeping a reference to it. This singleton class can have man observers or alternatively use NSNotificationCenter (see below).
2. In the second case, you should think about using NSNotificationCenter. Triggering a NSNotification would let observers know (ScheduleVC should be an observer) that something of their interest happened and update the UI accordingly. This pattern can also be used if you have a singleton class, it can trigger a NSNotification when some parts of the UI need to be updated.

In any case you'll end up with a nicely decoupled architecture that doesn't depend on the UI/VC structure.

Comment: It actually is to update the UI. I'll look at NSNotification.

Comment: Check this tutorial then: http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would have been helpful to know what kind of subclasses these objects are (`UIViewController`, `UIView`, `NSObject`).
Personally, I like to use the Model View Controller design format, and this will help you get rid of some of the issues you are having. ([Some good documentation for MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html), also, Professor Paul Hegarty gives classes on iTunes U that cover this topic).
There are a couple of things in your design pattern that conflict with the MVC pattern, and when fixed, will really help you out.

```
ScheduleVC who owns        
    ScheduleCell who owns  // controller owns view, this checks out

        ScheduleDayTVC who owns    // view owns another view controller, does not check out
            ScheduleDayCell who owns // controller owns view, would check out if the controller was not controlled by view higher up the chain.
                OrderDetailView      // view owns view, this checks out
```

The biggest piece of advice I can give is that you should switch to the MVC pattern, and stick to it. It helps keep everything organized in a logical way.

Comment: I added the subclasses